# ie6 css background image problem

Tags: internet-explorer-6, css

I have a CSS style which displays a png image in background. It works well in all browser, except in ie6.

In ie6 the bacground image is stretched to fit the block. How do I solve this ? Here's the CSS which I'm using to do this.

```
.error
{
    color: #D8000C;
    background-color: #FFBABA;
    background-image: url('error.png');
}
```

**IE7 / FF3.5**

[image]

**IE6**

[image]

Comment: Is that image a transparent PNG?

Comment: I've never seen that before happen!

Answer (score 4):

You probably use a png transparency fix script for IE6, I think the problem lies there because it probably applies a scale method.

Read the comments on [this page](http://allinthehead.com/retro/289/sleight-update-alpha-png-backgrounds-in-ie).

The documentation of your png transparency fix will probably cover this.

I personally found using transparent pngs in IE 6.0 to be a major pain in the ass despite all the various fixes out there. I know this is not an original answer, but I would probably just do a conditional check and replace the image with a gif or jpg version if you really need to support IE 6.0 here, instead of relying on hacks to support this. Or just drop IE 6.0 already, this year, I've talked every single client into not supporting IE 6.0 on their new projects. Seriously, it's about damn time that thing stopped making our professional lives so god damn miserable.

Comment: m already using JQuery PNGFix plugin for this and its working well across all browsers but this problem still persists on ie6

Comment: Listen to strager, the plugin you use will be using AlphaImageLoader to render it... It's obvious that this works well across other browsers because they don't need the pngFix in the first place

Comment: "... it's about damn time that thing stopped making our professional lives so god damn miserable." I like it

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [`AlphaImageLoader` filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969(VS.85).aspx), make sure `sizingMethod='scale'` is not present.  Remove it or set it to `image` instead of `scale`.

Comment: m not using AlphaImageLoader.

Comment: @s_ruchit, Yes you are.  The plugin you are using uses the filter.  Edit its source code and possibly contact the author of the plugin about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Belatedpng is the best script I have found for this problem:
http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

Answer (score -1):

set actual width and height for the background image and background-position.

```
    .error
{
    color: #D8000C;
    background-color: #FFBABA;
    background-image: url('error.png');
    background-position:left;
    width:251px; 
    height:72px; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

here width and height are actual size of the error.png image. hope it helps.

Comment: this will not work. width and height will be applied to the element that implements the style 'error'.

Comment: This *can* work if you add another element in the div with the image's size, and let the image stretch to it. However, this would be a workaround...